# Let $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be continuous. Show that $m(\mathcal{G})=0$, where $\mathcal{G}= \{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in [0,1]\}.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be continuous. Show that $m(\mathcal{G})=0$, where $\mathcal{G}= \{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in [0,1]\}.$

Since $f$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact we know that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. Now that means that for all $(x,y)$ we have that $$|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon : |x-y| < \delta$$ for all $\varepsilon >0$.

Apparently the idea here is to cover $\mathcal{G}$ by rectangles and use the uniform continuity. I got a hint that I can let $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $n\delta > |b-a| = |1-0| = 1$ and that there would then exist a partition $$0=x_0<x_1< \dots < x_n=1$$ such that $$|x_{i+1}-x_i| < \delta.$$

I'm bit confused where did this $n\delta > |b-a|$ come from and how does that imply $|x_{i+1}-x_i| < \delta$?

Comment: presumably $m$ is Lebesgue mesure in $\mathbb{R}^2$, right? You can use $\varepsilon$-arguments by covering the graph with small boxes adding up to $\varepsilon$ using uniform continuity. If you know Fubini's theorem, that you can get s short answer.

Comment: It seems that this has been asked and answered many times before: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmeasure-theory%5D+graph+zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By uniform continuity, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $0<\delta<1$ and such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$
Divide $[0,1]$ in small subintervals of length $\frac{1}{n}<\delta$. Then, the graph of $f$ over $[0,1]$ can be covered by $n$ small boxes of area $\frac{1}{n}2\varepsilon$. Adding up the areas these boxes gives $n\frac{1}{n}2\varepsilon=2\varepsilon$. As $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, one concludes that $m(\{(x,f(x):1\leq x\leq 1\})=0$.

A shorter proof may be obtained by appealing to Fubini's theorem.
$$\int_{[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{\mathcal{G}}(x,y)\,dxdy=\int^1_0\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{1}_{\mathcal{G}_x}(y)\,dy\Big)\,dx=\int^1_0\lambda(\{f(x)\})\,dx=0
$$
Since the Lebesgue measure (in $\mathbb{R}$) of a singleton is $0$

Comment: the shorter proof seems to hold for any $f$

Comment: @Exodd: measurable, that is.